# Вставление символов в строку

Tags: c++, строки, insert

Я пользовалась функцией insert для вставления символа в строку следующим образом:

```
s1 = "a";
for (int i = 1; i <= s.size(); ++i){
    s.insert(i, s1);
    ...
}
cout << s << "\n";
```

Однако получилось, что insert бесконечно вставляет символы, и даже не доходит до следующей итерации цикла. Почему так происходит?
Поход на cppreference ничего не дал.

Comment: потому что при вставке Ваша строка "увеличивается". Есть два способа обойти это - вставлять с конца или сформировать новую строку.

Comment: ясно, проще руками вставлять